# Number on all pages of table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I have this issue with a LaTeX document: I want to have page numbers on every page of the `Table of Content`. In my case the ToC is displayed across two pages because of many chapters in the text, but the first page of the ToC does not show a page number (the second page does). I generate the ToC like this:

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `\pagestyle{plain}`?

Comment: it's completely without page numbers. Probably because of \pagestyle{empty} on previous screens.

Comment: @JiříVlašimský: What document class are you using (perhaps [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)? It is customary for the first page of the ToC to be set similarly to what a regular `\chapter*` should look like. And these have their first pages set to `plain` using `\thispagestyle`. However, subsequent page should follow whatever `\pagestyle` you set before it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342044/latex-number-on-all-pages-of-table-of-content?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Do you want to set the page number of your toc?

Comment: @JiříVlašimský: I reworded your question to make it clearer. Please check whether I understood you. (And add more information about the code, e.g. used class.)

Answer (score 3):

In your preamble, add

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{keeppage}{\let\thispagestyle=\@gobble}{}
\makeatother
```

And wrap the table of contents like so:

```
\begin{keeppage}
    \tableofcontents
\end{keeppage}
```

This also works for chapters, title pages, and such.